# lambda function accessing outside variable

Tags: python, scope

I wanted to play around with anonymous functions so I decided to make a simple prime finder. Here it is:

```py
tests = []
end = int(1e2)
i = 3
while i <= end:
    a = map(lambda f:f(i),tests)
    if True not in a:
        tests.append(lambda x:x%i==0)
        print i
    print tests
    print "Test: "+str(i)
    print str(a)
    i+=2
```

What I find however, is that the `i` in the `lambda x:x%i==0` is accessed each time, while i want it to be a literal number. how can I get it to become `lambda x:x%3==0` instead?

Comment: Also see [These Nasty Closures](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271/) for a better explanation than the one in the official docs. But the short version is that each of these test functions is effectively a closure around the same variable `i`, and `i` keeps changing value. (This isn't quite accurate, because global variables don't actually need to be stored in closures, but the effect is the same.)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can "capture" the `i` when creating the lambda

```
lambda x, i=i: x%i==0
```

This will set the `i` in the lambda's context equal to whatever `i` was when it was created.  you could also say  `lambda x, n=i: x%n==0` if you wanted. It's not exactly capture, but it gets you what you need.

---

It's an issue of lookup that's analogous to the following with defined functions:

```
glob = "original"

def print_glob():
    print(glob) # prints "changed" when called below

def print_param(param=glob): # default set at function creation, not call
    print(param) # prints "original" when called below


glob = "changed"
print_glob()
print_param()
```

Comment: This works because default arguments are evaluated when the function is *created*, whereas variable look up is done when the function is *called*.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that each of those functions in `tests` is referring to the variable `i`.

More commonly, you do this inside a function, in which case you have a local-to-the-defining-scope variable `i`, which gets stored in a closure, as nicely explained in [These Nasty Closures](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502271/).

But here, it's even simpler: `i` is a global variable, so there is no closure. The functions are compiled to look up `i` as a global variable when run. Since `i` has changed, the functions will see the changed value when they run. Simple as that.

---

The traditional way around this (which works for both closures and globals) is fondly known as "the default-value hack", even though it's not really a hack. (See [the explanation in the FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects).) Ryan Haining's answer explains how to do this:

```
lambda x, i=i: x%i==0
```

This creates a parameter named `i`, with a default value equal to the value of `i` at the time the function is created. Then, inside the function, when you access parameter `i`, and you get that value.

---

A different way around this, which may seem more familiar if you're using to languages like JavaScript, is to create a function-creating function, and pass the value of `i` as an argument to that function-creating function, as in user2864740's answer:

```
(lambda i: lambda x: x%i)(i)
```

This avoids "polluting" the signature of the function with an extra parameter (that someone could accidentally pass an argument to), but at the cost of creating and calling a function for no good reason.

---

A third way around this is to use `partial`. In cases where all you're trying to do is partially apply a function, using `partial` instead of defining a wrapper function as a `lambda` can be cleaner.

Unfortunately, in this case, the function is hidden inside an operator, and the function `operator.mod` that exposes it doesn't take keyword arguments, so you can't usefully partial its second operand. So, this is a bad solution in this case. If you really wanted to, you could just write a wrapper that behaves better and `partial` that:

```
def opmod(a, b):
    return a % b

partial(operator.mod, b=i)
```

In this case, I think you're better off with the other solutions; just keep this one in your head for cases where it *is* appropriate.

Comment: I could not find anything related to that on the link you provided.

Comment: @erm3nda There are at least two links in the answer, and I have no idea what "that" refers to in your comment.

Comment: Sorry. About the default value hack at http://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects

Comment: @erm3nda Ah, that seems to be in the Programming chapter of the FAQ, not the Design chapter. I don't know if that changed over the last 4 years, or if you were the first one to actually follow the link in all that time, but either way, thanks for catching it, and I'll edit.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result thanks.

Comment: @erm3nda By the way, something that helps me for understanding, which both links make a bit more confusing rather than helping, is that the difference between Python vs. say, many Lisps has nothing to do with closures, but with looping. In both languages, `i` closes over the local variable. But in Python, we're updating that local variable after the closure is being created, while in most Lisps, we're either recursing, or using a macro that creates a new variable each time through the loop, not `setq`ing the variable; either way, the variable we capture never changes, so things just work.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new function that returns the lambda. Then call that, passing in `i` as an argument. This will create a new binding scope.

```
def make_test (i):
   # this i refers to the parameter (which evaluates to the /value/ passed)
   return lambda x: x%i==0

# ..
# the /value/ resulting from evaluating the variable is passed
tests.append(make_test(i))
```