# Python lambda function with indexing

Tags: python, lambda

I know similar questions have been asked, but I have no idea how to apply it to my problem. I am trying to create a tuple with lambda functions which call an array index.

```
cons=()
for i in range(5):
    cons = cons + (lambda x: x[i],)
```

All the functions in the tuple use the latest value of `i`, instead of the initial value. How do I fix this in this example?

*Just for completeness sake, I have solved my problem with the below solution:*

```
def indexi(x,j):
  return(x[j])

def indexii():
    for i in range(5):
        yield(partial(indexi, j=i))

cons=()
for func in indexii():
    cons += (func_,)
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053988/lambda-function-acessing-outside-variable

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you could use `operator.itemgetter` instead of the lambda function