# lambda to assign a value to global variable?

Tags: python, lambda, assign

I'm using tkinter and trying to assign a value to a global variable on a button press. Here is the code:

```
popup.add_command(label="Allow Moving Item", command=lambda: allowMoving=True)
```

I'm getting the invalid syntax. Can you tell me how to work this around?

Comment: Use functions. Don't use global variables.

Comment: Avoid global variables. If you need an answer, refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21054384/1627968.

Comment: `command=lambda: allowMoving=True` --> `SyntaxError: can't assign to lambda` (`lambda`s may only contain an expression, no statements.) Replace it with the name of a normally defined function.

Comment: Anonymous functions are defined by lambda *expressions*, which cannot contain an assignment (or any other kind of) *statement*.

Comment: Callbacks don't need to use `lambda` syntax.

Answer (score 6):

For entertainment purposes only.

```
popup.add_command(label="Allow Moving Item",
                  command=lambda: globals().update(allowMoving=True))
```

(Although `globals()` is not documented with the same "do not modify the return value" warning as `locals()`, I'm still not sure this is guaranteed to work.)

---

A better answer would be to define the callback with a `def` statement instead.

```
def set_allow_moving():
    global allow_moving    # Don't use camel case for variable names in Python
    allow_moving = True

popup.add_command(label="Allow Moving Item", command=set_allow_moving)
```

Comment: Thanks, the globals().update(allowMoving=True) method works. The additional question - if it was local variable, can I change it without globals? P.S. I do not necessary need lambda

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `lambda`. A good rule of thumb is to never use `lambda` unless there's simply no other way. The use of `lambda` in callbacks should be the exception rather than the rule.

```
def allow_moving():
    global allowMoving
    allowMoving = True

popup.add_command(label="Allow Moving Item", command=allow_moving)
```