# Appending map functions to PySpark RDD inside for loop

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Could someone please help me understand the behaviour of appending map functions to an RDD in a python for loop?

For the following code:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([[1], [2], [3]])

def appender(l, i):
    return l + [i]

for i in range(3):
    rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: appender(x, i))

rdd.collect()
```

I get the output:

```
[[1, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Whereas with the following code:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([[1], [2], [3]])

def appender(l, i):
    return l + [i]

rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: appender(x, 1))
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: appender(x, 2))
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: appender(x, 3))

rdd.collect()
```

I get the expected output:

```
[[1, 1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2, 3]]
```

I imagine this has something to do with the closure that is passed to the PySpark  compiler, but I can't find any documentation about this...

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to store all global variables (in this case `i`) in the lambda function to ensure proper closure. This can be accomplished by

```
for i in range(3):
    rdd = rdd.map(lambda x, i=i: appender(x, i))
```

More information about this can be found at [lambda function accessing outside variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053988/lambda-function-acessing-outside-variable).

Interestingly, at least on a local cluster (have not tested on distributed clusters), the problem can also be addressed by persisting the intermediate rdd:

```
for i in range(3):
    rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: appender(x, i))
    rdd.persist()
```

both solutions produce

```
[[1, 0, 1, 2], [2, 0, 1, 2], [3, 0, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is because of lazy evaluation:
And also You had a bad range.

this two code snippets results in the same output:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([[1], [2], [3]])

def appender(l, i):
    return l + [i]

for i in range(1,4):
    rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rdd.map(lambda x: appender(x, i)).collect())

rdd.collect()
```

outputs:

```
[[1, 1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2, 3]]
```

and second one :

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([[1], [2], [3]])

rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: appender(x, 1))
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: appender(x, 2))
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: appender(x, 3))

rdd.collect()
```

outputs:

```
[[1, 1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2, 3]]
```

---

Also, to show what happens in for loop in simplified example ( only inputs 1 and 2 ) with modified appender function to print l argument:

1. for loop prints :

   ```
   [2]
   [2, 2]
   [1]
   [3]
   [1, 2]
   [3, 2]
   ```

as firstly it gets second field from input list

2. explicit writing of mappers output is:

   ```
   [1]
   [1, 1]
   [2]
   [2, 1]
   [3]
   [3, 1]
   ```

Comment: Hmm, nothing wrong with that range from my (and my python interpreter's) perspective. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Comment: Parallelizing the rdd.map function is certainly not what I want to do either. Parallelize should be used to distribute an existing collection over the cluster. Bear in mind that this is just test pseudo-code.

Comment: `
Python 2.7.12
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print(i)
0
1
2
`
and in second snippet You put as input numbers : 1,2,3