# Python Qt (PySide2) window.findChild() ran in loop overwriting reference

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

So I have a a set of 8 LineEdits and 8 Checkboxes as the following image. I'm trying to save some code and connect each check to enable/disable its corresponding line.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8hv8.png)

It behaves fine if I set them individually, but saving code and writing a loop **only the last checkbox/lineedit pair is working**. It seems like the widget references are not evaluated in real-time but later on and only the last one is kept as I'm replacing the variable. Is this something related to PySide2 or python?

In the past have seen different widget behavior depending on which occasion app.exec_() was ran. Any thoughts why this happens?

Works as expected:

```
    le1 = w.findChild(QLineEdit, 'lineedit_addr1')
    check1 = w.findChild(QCheckBox, 'check_enabled1')
    check1.stateChanged.connect(lambda: le1.setEnabled(check1.isChecked()))
    le2 = w.findChild(QLineEdit, 'lineedit_addr2')
    check2 = w.findChild(QCheckBox, 'check_enabled2')
    check2.stateChanged.connect(lambda: le2.setEnabled(check2.isChecked()))
    
'...'
    le8 = w.findChild(QLineEdit, 'lineedit_addr8')
    check8 = w.findChild(QCheckBox, 'check_enabled8')
    check8.stateChanged.connect(lambda: le8.setEnabled(check8.isChecked()))
```

Only last check row works as expected:

```
    lineedits = [w.findChild(QLineEdit, 'lineedit_addr{}'.format(i)) for i in range(1,9)]
    checks = [w.findChild(QCheckBox, 'check_enabled{}'.format(i)) for i in range(1,9)]
    for le,check in zip(lineedits,checks):
        check.stateChanged.connect(lambda: le.setEnabled(check.isChecked()))
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]..

Comment: There's really no point in using lambdas when a signal already provides the required argument of the target function. Just change to `check.toggled.connect(le.setEnabled)`.

Comment: You could also encapsulate the current lambda inside another lambda, which returns it when executed: `check.stateChanged.connect((lambda l, c: (lambda: l.setEnabled(c.isChecked())))(le, check))`.

Comment: Thank you @musicamante and whoever tagged as duplicate of lambda closures. It is indeed the issue and will try to avoid lambdas in loops in the future. `toggled` signal connected solves the issue. The double lambda seems very ugly

Comment: @fsv there's no need to avoid it, you just need to understand what you're doing. Read the comment of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21054087/14956120), its gold. In my example, I use lambda encapsulation because I discovered, through testing on my own, that it is more reliable to use it when dealing with qt objects (sometimes, captures do not work properly, and the app crashes). Even so, it's totally safe to use lambdas for signals and slots, but in the post's example, it is redundant as check.stateChanged does have a parameter (but note that in the docs, its an int, not a boolean).

Comment: @fsv I've never said you should never use lambdas. As Carl also states, you must understand what you're doing and how they work, and most of the times it's better (and simpler) to use them. In your case, they can be avoided because there is a signal argument that is compatible with the target function (that's why I specifically used `toggled` instead of `stateChanged`) and is specifically related to its context, but sometimes it's not possible, and creating ad hoc functions may complicate things because you may need to take dynamic arguments that include the target objects. Supposing that »

Comment: @fsv the source object didn't provide a compatible signal, the lambda should use keyworded argument to *capture* everything that may become *variable* within the scope of the loop. For instance, if you have object `A` that sends a signal having an argument, which should do something on object `B` based on the state of `C`, then: `A.someSignal(lambda argOfA, b=B, c=C: b.doSomething(c.something())` (note the letter casings). The important thing to remember is that signal arguments are *always* sent and should be used as positional arguments, while everything else is used as keyword argument.

Comment: @CarlHR While that works, it *is* ugly. At that point, a local function (created in the loop) that returns a wrapped function would be better, as it would be fundamentally identical, but much more readable. OTOH, I'm curious about the issues you mentioned; can you provide examples of cases for such situations?

Comment: @musicamante Thanks . This works well

```
    lineedits = [w.findChild(QLineEdit, 'lineedit_addr{}'.format(i)) for i in range(1,9)]
    checks = [w.findChild(QCheckBox, 'check_enabled{}'.format(i)) for i in range(1,9)]
    for le,check in zip(lineedits,checks):
        `check.stateChanged.connect(lambda arg, _widget=le: _widget.setEnabled(arg))`
```

but this doesn't 

```  
 `check.stateChanged.connect(lambda arg, _widget=le, _state=check.isChecked(): _widget.setEnabled(_state))`

```
any ideas why?

Comment: @fsv That doesn't work because the value of the keyword argument is evaluated *during* the loop iteration. At that moment, `check.isChecked()` probably returns `False`, and that means that `_state` will be `False` from that moment on, until the signal is emitted.